# HBase master is immediately getting down

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

My hadoop servers are got down because of disk space issue,then we increased disk space then HDFS,zookeeper,kafka started working but HBase is not working.

**It is throwing below exception while restarting Hbase from Ambari.**

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FileSystemVersionException: HBase file layout needs to be upgraded. You have version null and I want version 8. Consult http://hbase.apache.org/book.html for further information about upgrading HBase. Is your hbase.rootdir valid? If so, you may need to run 'hbase hbck -fixVersionFile'.
```

Based on the suggestion I ran the command `hbase hbck -fixVersionFile` as a hbase user, then I am getting error like this:

```
2019-12-10 19:04:59,535 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-slave01.testiot.cloud:2181,slave02.testiot.cloud:2181,slave03.testiot.cloud:2181@0x619bfe29-SendThread(slave02.testiot.cloud:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.1.0.5:39250, server: slave02.testiot.cloud/10.1.0.7:2181
2019-12-10 19:04:59,560 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-slave01.testiot.cloud:2181,slave02.testiot.cloud:2181,slave03.testiot.cloud:2181@0x619bfe29-SendThread(slave02.testiot.cloud:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server slave02.testiot.cloud/10.1.0.7:2181, sessionid = 0x26ef0e604f530e3, negotiated timeout = 60000
2019-12-10 19:05:03,908 INFO  [main] client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl: Call exception, tries=6, retries=36, started=4163 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=java.io.IOException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase-unsecure/master, details=
2019-12-10 19:05:07,945 INFO  [main] client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl: Call exception, tries=7, retries=36, started=8200 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=java.io.IOException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase-unsecure/master, details=
2019-12-10 19:05:17,964 INFO  [main] client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl: Call exception, tries=8, retries=36, started=18219 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=java.io.IOException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase-unsecure/master, details=
2019-12-10 19:05:28,024 INFO  [main] client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl: Call exception, tries=9, retries=36, started=28279 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=java.io.IOException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase-unsecure/master, details=
```

I am running a cluster of three nodes. When I checked hbase.root.dir hbase.version file was not there.

```
HbaseVersion -2.0.2
zookeeper - 3.4.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included the hbase version file from another server. Now its working fine.

Comment: but we lost the old data.